# Glassfish MethodExecutor Exception

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am getting the following error upon deploying a fairly simple Spring MVC app on Glassfish.  I believe it has to do with a memory leak somewhere, but there really isn't any indication of where it could be.

Does this look like an application issue or a setting on the app server that I can change?

I was previously getting a Statement Leak detection error, but I lowered the connections  on the JDBC pool and that went away.  I am using JDBCTemplate, so I don't think I need to close any connections manually.

Can someone advise where the best place to start looking would be?

```
SEVERE: Exception while visiting com/sun/gjc/util/MethodExecutor.class of size 6337
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType(TypesImpl.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor.visit(ModelClassVisitor.java:119)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.JarArchive.onSelectedEntries(JarArchive.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```